# Convert CSPro .map to ArcGIS shapefile?

Tags: shapefile, convert

I have census data that uses the widely-established [CSPro](http://www.census.gov/population/international/software/cspro/) software.  It also comes with a Map viewer and the data files are .map and .mdf extensions.

Does anyone know how to convert these into an ArcGIS shapefile?  CSPro gives instructions on how to convert an ESRI shapefile to CSpro format but not the other way round.  It must be possible, but I do not know how.  I've tried OGR2GUI but without success - it does not recognize .map file extensions.

Comment: can you export out of cspro? csv?